# Fenics: msh to xml conversion

Tags: fenics, mesh

I generated a mesh file in gambit and wanted to convert it to xml format. I tried the code below, but there is no output.

```
from dolfin import *    
from dolfin_utils import meshconvert

dolfin-convert cylinder6.msh out.xml
```

can anyone tell me how to convert using dolfin??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use dolfin-convert from a terminal window.

Comment: Hi I converted some other mesh file found in web but not exactly the file which was generated in gambit...is there any other conversion for gambit generated mesh ??

Comment: I am not familiar with gambit generated meshes. Maybe you could upload a small sample mesh? Note that FEniCS only currently support simplices (triangles/tets).

Answer (score 2):

To see which mesh types dolfin-convert can handle see the command line help:

```
$ dolfin-convert 
Usage: dolfin-convert [OPTIONS] ... input.x output.y

Options:

  -h         display this help text and exit
  -i format  specify input format
  -o format  specify output format

Alternatively, the following long options may be used:

  --help     same as -h
  --input    same as -i
  --output   same as -o

Supported formats:

  xml      - DOLFIN XML mesh format (current)
  xml-old  - DOLFIN XML mesh format (DOLFIN 0.6.2 and earlier)
  mesh     - Medit, generated by tetgen with option -g
  Triangle - Triangle file format (input prefix of .ele and .node files)
  gmsh     - Gmsh, version 2.0 file format
  metis    - Metis graph file format
  scotch   - Scotch graph file format
  diffpack - Diffpack tetrahedral grid format
  abaqus   - Abaqus tetrahedral grid format
  ExodusII - Sandia Format (requires ncdump utility from NetCDF)
  Star-CD  - Star-CD tetrahedral grid format

If --input or --output are not specified, the format will
be deduced from the suffix:

  .xml  - xml
  .mesh - mesh
  .gmsh - gmsh
  .msh  - gmsh
  .gra  - metis
  .grf  - scotch
  .grid - diffpack
  .inp  - abaqus
  .e    - Exodus II
  .exo  - Exodus II
  .ncdf - ncdump'ed Exodus II
  .vrt and .cell  - starcd
```

To call dolfin mesh conversion utilities from python, try:

```
from dolfin_utils import meshconvert

# Convert to XML
meshconvert.convert2xml(ifilename, ofilename, iformat=iformat)
```

but then you have to order the mesh yourself (or call the command dolfin-order)

```
# Order mesh
os.system("dolfin-order %s" % ofilename)
```

Answer (score 2):

[meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (a small project of mine) has as command-line tool that can do it:

```
meshio-convert cylinder6.msh out.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a shell script (such as `dolfin-convert`) from python, you have to pass the necessary command line to the shell via `os.system()`, e.g.,

```
import os
os.system('dolfin-convert carbon_f.msh mesh.xml')
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a little bit?